# Room: related entities - usable public constructor

Tags: android, kotlin, entities, android-room, android-architecture-components

To get a OneToMany relation with Room I create a POJO with @Embedded object and [@Relation](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/arch/persistence/room/Relation.html) variable.

```
data class SubjectView(
    @Embedded
    var subject: Subject,

    @Relation(parentColumn = "idWeb", entityColumn = "subject_id", entity = Topic::class)
    var topics: List<Topic>?
)
```

But while compiling I have this error

```
 error: Entities and Pojos must have a usable public constructor. You can have an empty constructor or a constructor whose parameters match the fields (by name and type)
[...]
Tried the following constructors but they failed to match:
SubjectView(biz.eventually.atpl.data.db.Subject,java.util.List<biz.eventually.atpl.data.db.Topic>) : [subject : subject, topics : null]
```

Well, that constructor **[subject : subject, topics : null]** looks like the good one ???

However, if I change my class with no-arg constructor and an all params constructor, it does work.

```
class SubjectView() {
    @Embedded
    var subject: Subject = Subject(-1, -1, "")

    @Relation(parentColumn = "idWeb", entityColumn = "subject_id", entity = Topic::class)
    var topics: List<Topic>? = null

    constructor(subject: Subject, topics: List<Topic>?) : this() {
        this.subject = subject
        this.topics = topics
    }
}
```

I would like to know why the first (quicker) version does not compile, as it is not as the documentation shows.

Default args for all variables (as I could have seen on other post) in a constructor (data) class seems not to be mandatory though?

Thanks

Answer (score 5, accepted):

There are several topics how data class generate the constructors.

Since you have a nullable Object inside your constructor, it will generate all possible constructors. That means it generates

```
constructor(var subject: Subject)
constructor(var subject: Subject, var topics: List<Topic>)
```

There are two ways to solve that. The first one is to predefine all values like and create another ignored constructor with the desired constructor.

```
data class SubjectView(
    @Embedded
    var subject: Subject,

    @Relation(parentColumn = "idWeb", entityColumn = "subject_id", entity = Topic::class)
    var topics: List<Topic> = ArrayList()
) {
 @Ignore constructor(var subject: Subject) : this(subject, ArrayList())
}
```

Another way is creating a half-filled data class like

```
data class SubjectView(@Embedded var subject: Subject) {
    @Relation var topics: List<Topic> = ArrayList()
}
```

Take care that the first solution is the proper solution and you need to set @Ignore to any other constructor.

Comment: Hi! I don't understand your answer because you make `topics` non null. Or we want `topics` to be nullable...

Comment: Even if you want to be nullable you should create an instance of Topic and validate if the entries are "empty", not null.

Comment: Or add the @JvmOverloads annotation to the main class constructor like

`data class SubjectView @JvmOverloads constructor(...)`

Comment: first mistake beginners do.. using jvmoverloads. Try to avoid them if you dont need them. There are many cons why using JvmOverloads is bad. (Compile time, speed, generated code, ..)

Comment: I'm slightly confused at your initial statement. From my understanding, multiple constructors are only generated when you use **default** arguments, not just when you use nullable arguments.